# How to create a min heap of fixed size using std::priority_queue?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I can define a min heap as:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater> pq;
```

I have a stream of integers. The min heap's size is a fixed value k. It seems that priority_queue can not do this.

Comment: Do you really mean a fixed size, or do you mean a maximum size? If the size is really fixed, what `k` initial values are in the queue?

Comment: Basically, it is a min heap of size k. The purpose is to find the k smallest numbers of a stream of numbers.

Comment: Which doesn't answer the question rici asked at all. Do you start out with a size of `k`, or do you start with an empty heap and do not want the number of elements to grow beyond `k`? If it's the former, then what are the `k` integers you place in the heap to begin with?

Comment: "The purpose is to find the k smallest numbers of a stream of numbers." Why don't you sort the stream and take the first k elements?

Comment: @101010: Because that's why you use a heap with bounded size. Sorting the whole data set requires that you pull the whole dataset into memory at once (or deal with spilling to disk and rereading), and it's `O(n log n)` work. Using a bounded size heap to do the work reduces the work to `O(n log k)` where `n` is the size of the input stream, and `k` is the size of the (presumably much smaller) bounded heap..

Comment: And to be clear, the computational benefit isn't even the biggest win. If you're getting the 16 smallest or largest elements, pulling `2**32` elements from a stream (say, processing a file iteratively), sorting the whole damn thing would require at least `2**32 * sizeof(element)` memory (depending on the sort algorithm, you might need twice that), which is going to be a problem on a 32 bit machine (or a 64 bit machine that doesn't have oodles of RAM). With a heap, you use `16 * sizeof(element)` memory; for that, even 640KB is enough (in practice, fitting in CPU cache makes it run even faster).

Comment: For off-line small lists, `std::partial_sort` does have the same run-time complexity though.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `std::priority_queue`, it's trivial to limit the size of the queue to `k` elements. Note however that you need to use a max heap, not a min heap, because you need to know whether a newly arrived value should be inserted into the heap, which will happen if it is smaller than the maximum value currently in the heap.

```
class Topk {
  public:
    Topk(int k) : k_(k) {}
    void insert(int value) {
      if (q_.size() < k_) q_.push(value);
      else if (value < q_.top()) { q_.pop(); q_.push(value); }
    }
    std::vector<int> finalize() {
      std::vector<int> result(q_.size());
      while (q_.size()) {
        result[q_.size() - 1] = q_.top();
        q_.pop();
      }
      return result;
    }
  private:
    int k_;
    std::priority_queue<int> q_;
}
```

Just using the heap algorithms is really not more complicated:

```
class Topk {
  public:
    Topk(int k) : k_(k) {}
    void insert(int value) {
      if (c_.size() < k_) {
        c_.push_back(value);
        if (c_.size() == k_) make_heap(c_.begin(), c_.end());
      }
      else if (value < c_[0]) {
        /* See note below */
        pop_heap(c_.begin(), c_.end());
        c_.back() = value;
        push_heap(c_.begin(), c_.end());
      }
    }
    std::vector<int> finalize() {
      if (c_.size() < k_)
        std::sort(c_.begin(), c_.end());
      else
        sort_heap(c_.begin(), c_end());
      std::vector<int> c;
      std::swap(c, c_);
      return std::move(c);
    }
  private:
    /* invariant: if c_.size() == k, then c_ is a maxheap. */
    int k_;
    std::vector<int> c_;
}
```

Note: `<algorithm>` does not include a `heap_sift_down` operation, which is unfortunate for this application; the pop / swap / push operation could be replaced with swap / sift_down. That's still O(log k), but it is probably slightly faster.

Comment: I think for the implementation using priority_queue, for `'void insert(int value) {
      if (q_.size() < k_) q_.push(value);
      else if (value < q_.top()) { q_.pop(); q_.push(value); }
    }`, 'if (q_.size() < k_)', should remove the last element of q_, not the top element of q_.

Comment: @john: if the queue is not full, nothing is removed. If it is full and the new value should be remembered, we need to ditch the least important queued value, which is the max. Which is top.

Comment: `@rici:`Yes. I mean when the queue is full (`'if (q_.size() > k_)`). You implemented a "MIN HEAP" by using a max heap. Am I right?

Comment: q.size cannot be > k_. At most it is equal. And it is a real max heap; there is no trickery.

Comment: `@rici`The purpose of the max K heap is to maintain the largest K items. Assume there are a stream of integers coming. We keep adding the integers to the max K heap. In the end we can find the largest K integers. When the queue is full, `(q_.size() == k_)`, we should remove the last item in the queue. If we remove the `q_.top()`, it is not correct.

Comment: @John: The purpose of the heap is to keep the K *smallest* items; that is what you asked for. Since it is a max heap, it always knows which of the k smallest items is the largest, since that is the one we need to discard when we find a new item which fits in the smallest set.

Comment: @John: I'm assuming you are using the specification in your comment from two days ago: "The purpose is to find the k *smallest* numbers of a stream of numbers.". That comment should really be edited into the question.

Comment: `@rici` During the discussion, it deviated from my original post. I want to know how to implement "min k heap" and "max k heap" with priority_queue. Your implementation is a "MIN K HEAP" by using a max heap. Am I right?

Comment: @john: a min heap is a data sructure which can tell you in O(1) what the minimum contained element is. It has nothing to do with what you put in it. If you want to collect the k smallest elements of a stream, you can do that with any data structure: a vector,va linked list, or a heap. That doesnt make those things min vectors, min lists and min heaps. As it happens, a good data structure to maintain the collection of smallest elements is a max heap, for reasons i have trued several times to explain.

Comment: `@rici` I got it. If I need to maintain a collection of largest elements, I just pass a comparator to `std::priority_queue<int> q_;`, like `std::priority_queue<int, vector<int>, mycomparator> q_;`, right?

Comment: @john if you want to keep the largest elements so you need to alwys evict the smallest element, so you need a min-heap. A min-heap uses `greater` as its comparator.

Comment: Rookie question: I wonder why not return `c_` in the second example instead of doing `std::swap(c, c_);    return std::move(c);`

Comment: @Unni: The idea is to reset the `Topk` object and return the vector without copying the elements. The swap resets `c_` to an empty vector, and the `move` arranges for the original to be returned using move semantics rather than copy semantics.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an iterator, and you don't need to do it in asynchronously, you can use `std::partial_sort`.

```
std::vector<int> x{10, 5, 1, 2, 3};
std::partial_sort(x.begin(), x.begin() + k, x.end());
```

This gives the first k elements with roughly `O(nlogk)` run-time complexity.